# Mercurial Merge has unexpectedly deleted source files

Tags: mercurial, merge, fault

We have encountered a situation with Hg where no matter which way we merge two branches it wants to delete hundreds of files completely unexpectedly.
i.e. merge branch A into B or B into A.
More baffling no one has physically deleted them.

Has anyone experienced this and can give guidance - this has become a major issue for us?

Thanks.

Comment: You are more likely to get the required help by asking this in Mercurial's users mailing list.

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MailingLists#The_Mercurial_list

Comment: Very similar issue here too btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825269/crazy-merge-behaviour-in-mercurial-merge

Comment: What version of Mercurial are you using?

Comment: Is the project open? Meaning, can we take a look at the two branches and try to help you that way?

Comment: Small nitpick: a merge is *symmetric*. It does not matter if you do `hg update A; hg merge B` or the other way around. And please come talk to us on the mailinglist or on IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial

Comment: Can you show here results of hg merge -P and hg log for potentially deleted by merge files in both merge-parents? Because hg delete file on merge only if it was deleted in any parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments - this is same issue as my colleague posted and the answer is there.

Answer (score 0):

Could there be a rename of a folder/directory involved?  Perhaps one that's only a case change (ex: `Stuff`  to `stuff`)?  That could show up as a lot of deletions in some views, but of course isn't actually handled that way.

In short, it's extremely unlikely that what's happening is what it looks like is happening.  With more detail we can work together to figure it out, but if you got help in the Mailing list or IRC please provide a followup here too.